# Update errors on Xubuntu12.04

Tags: updates, xubuntu

I'm trying to install updates via the Update Manager, and I got this error:

> The Package system is broken Check if you are using third party
>   repositories. if so disable them, since they are a common source of
>   problems. Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: `apt-get
>   install -f`

When I run `apt-get install -f`, I get:

```
E: could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission Denied   E: Unable to lock administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

What is wrong? How do I fix it? Why does this happen?

EDIT:

This is what i get when i do `sudo apt-get install -f`

[1] https://www.dropbox.com/s/tzr0s8278pbe9sm/2012-07-03%2019.34.07.jpg

[2] https://www.dropbox.com/s/xmllkxvpa3weg33/2012-07-03%2019.34.52.jpg

[3] https://www.dropbox.com/s/n799fxp3iv44cd4/2012-07-03%2019.35.09.jpg

Picture are in the correct order. too much info for one picture so had to break it into 3 but all of the information is in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the sudo command that you need, your pictures show a "No space left on device" error; your hard drive is full!

Comment: it shouldn't be there are 2 hard drives. both 8GB when installing i made my own partitions so maybe that's why i will make the hard drives bigger when i reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get install -f` must be run as [root](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo), so run it like this instead:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

You'll be prompted for your password. As you enter it, you won't see anything, but that's OK--just type it in and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

That may fix your problem. If not, you can edit your question to provide more information (including the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`).

Comment: i added more info for you and the other to look at.