# Ubuntu packages don't get update

Tags: apt, updates, error-handling

I get this output:

```
7 packages can be updated.
7 updates are security updates.

Last login: Tue Apr 19 10:04:51 2016 from 10.0.0.199
```

whenever I connect to my server. and I still see these packages not updated!
And I AM root (`sudo su`).

When I `sudo apt-get update` I get this:

```
myserver@YHserver:~$ apt-get update
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denie                                                                                                                                                             d)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily InRelease
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates InRelease
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports InRelease
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Sources
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Sources
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Sources
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Sources
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main i386 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Translation-en
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Translation-en
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Sources
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main Sources
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe i386 Packages
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security InRelease [65.9 kB]
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Translation-en
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Sources [45.5 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Sources [2,854 B]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Sources [11.7 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Sources [2,782 B]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main amd64 Packages [145 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted amd64 Packages [10.9 k                                                                                                                                                             B]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe amd64 Packages [52.1 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [6,253                                                                                                                                                              B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main i386 Packages [142 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted i386 Packages [10.8 k                                                                                                                                                             B]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe i386 Packages [52.1 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse i386 Packages [6,430                                                                                                                                                              B]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Translation-en
Fetched 555 kB in 2s (227 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

what should I do to get it updated? It's security updates and it seems important

I always run `apt-get upgrade -y` after 'update'.

I DIDN'T delete the lock file and followed the 2nd comment to this post: 
[Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)
And this isn't helping. I cant see the process that's holding 'apt'

```
root      3004  0.0  0.0   9496  2260 pts/0    S+   10:32   0:00 grep --color=auto apt-get
root@YHserver:/home/myserver# kill -9 3004
bash: kill: (3004) - No such process
root@YHserver:/home/myserver# kill -9 2260
bash: kill: (2260) - No such process
root@YHserver:/home/myserver# kill -9 9496
bash: kill: (9496) - No such process
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while using apt-get install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/95633/error-while-using-apt-get-install)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update errors on Xubuntu12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/159101/update-errors-on-xubuntu12-04) – you need to run `apt-get update` (and all other operations that modify the package database) as super-user, i. e. with `sudo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denie                                                                                                                                                             d)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

This looks like you have some kind of permission problem.

```
myserver@YHserver ...
```

You should be root when doing update / upgrade. It looks like you are "myserver" instead of root. Do you connect to the machine via ssh, or directly ? ( You need to enable "root via ssh")

Please try to exec the commands patrick wrote and report the outcome here

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

If that does not help, please try the following:

```
su
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
```

Another possibilty that comes to my mind: Did you check for dist-upgrades ?

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` worked for me! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

i use that a lot and it will update any packages installed if there is an update available

Comment: I always run upgrade -y after i update. this doesn't solve it.

Comment: @Hatzil666: But using `sudo` should solve it.